# Populate table with data stored in separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union, create-table

I have a MySQL database `separate_data`, which consists of 200 tables with random names (for example `first_table`, `second_table`, ...)
Each of these tables have the same structure and indexes.
The total size is about 30GB.

I would like to copy all this data to a new MySQL database called `new_database`, in the table `all_data`, keeping the structure (but dropping the auto_increment column), and adding a column to indicate the original table.

So, for example, the situation is:

`first_table`

```
+----+------+------+
| id | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | aaa  | xxx  |
|  2 | aaa  | yyy  |
|  3 | bbb  | zzz  |
+----+------+------+
```

`second_table`

```
+----+------+------+
| id | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | aaa  | xxx  |
|  2 | ccc  | yyy  |
|  3 | ddd  | zzz  |
+----+------+------+
```

And the resulting `all_data` table should be

```
+------+------+---------------+
| Col2 | Col3 | Original      |
+------+------+---------------+
| aaa  | xxx  | first_table   |
| aaa  | yyy  | first_table   |
| bbb  | zzz  | first_table   |
| aaa  | xxx  | second_table  |
| ccc  | yyy  | second_table  |
| ddd  | zzz  | second_table  |
+------+------+---------------+
```

The problem is the amount of data. Doing this in PHP is not an option because of that. I'm fine with some manual work (for example creating a data dump for `separate_data` first and then injecting this data dump into the `new` database or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
create table all_data as
select col2, col3, 'first_table' as original from first_table
union all select col2, col3, 'second_table' from second_table
```

You would typically expand the query with more `union all` members for other related tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is there a way to say "take all tables from `separate_data`" instead of having to list them all?

Comment: @binoculars: no, you need to enumerate all the tables. Of course, you can generate the query string programmatically with the tool of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Come to think of it, I also would need a reference to the original table... I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I seem to run into `Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` . Apparently, this can be fixed by applying `SET @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = OFF; 
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = OFF_PERMISSIVE;` but for that I need SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privileges... Don't think I can do something about that since my database is a Managed Database Cluster on Digital Ocean?